# php- command does not work with php shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell-exec

I want to execute following command on my Ubuntu server using php:

```
android create project --target 8 --name $fname --path ./$fname --activity MainActivity --package $fpack 2>&1
```

The above command is to create an Android app project. So when I enter this command on my terminal then it works fine, but when I execute it via php:

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$fpack = $_POST['fpack'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//Creating a new Android project
var_dump(shell_exec("android create project --target 8 --name $fname --path ./$fname --activity MainActivity --package $fpack 2>&1"));

?>
```

When I run my PHP script I get the following output:

```
string(26) "sh: 1: android: not found "
```

Why it works when I enter manually in terminal (from user 'ashish' account) but not with php? my apache user and group is same (ashish). Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: If you installed Apache using LAMP, uninstall LAMP and install apache, mysql separately. It works for me.

Comment: The `android` program isn't in your `$PATH` or there are permissions in the way.

Answer (score 0):

see this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

exec — Execute an external program

so try to use
exec() insted shell_exec()

exec("android create project --target 8 --name $fname --path ./$fname --activity MainActivity --package $fpack 2>&1")

Answer (score 0):

changing from shell_exec to exec worked for me.

I was trying to run a script that had no output...

apparently it made a difference...

also changing the owner was important:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R <directory>
```

I am not sure if including this into the exec paramenter helped: `2>&1`